# generating xml on the hit of a button in a swing form

Tags: java, xml, swing

I have created the below swing form which will take some paramters
from user in the form and when user hit the button generatenetworkmodel an xml should be generated and in those xml the input value would be the same which user had eneterd in the text box as shown

The xml that i want to be generated and written in JTextPane within the form is is ..

```
  <route cna="trk" typ="e_pwap" ver="96" sk_cna="ltp6" sk_typ="55" sk_ver="26" prefilterfilename="sjj" prefiltertype="true" postfilterfilename="" postfiltertype="" xfm="" gelcatnumbersource="16" gelcatnumbersink="40" />
```

the user had eneterd this parameters for the above xml is ...

```
 route cna="trk"
 typ="e_pwap"
 ver="96"
 sk_cna="ltp6"
 sk_typ="55"
 sk_ver="26"
 prefilterfilename="sjj"
 prefiltertype="true"
 postfilterfilename=""
 postfiltertype=""
 xfm=""
 gelcatnumbersource="16"
 gelcatnumbersink="40"
```

now please advise the logic that i should write in the class ithself to generate the xml on the click of submit button

rite now my below code is shown below ...

```
package abcd;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class sdr {

    private JFrame frmArgonNetworkModel;
    private final JButton btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel = new JButton("GenerateAgonNetworkModel");
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    private JTextField textField_7;
    private JTextField textField_8;
    private JTextField textField_9;
    private JTextField textField_10;
    private JTextField textField_11;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sdr window = new sdr();
                    window.frmArgonNetworkModel.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public sdr() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmArgonNetworkModel = new JFrame();
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().setForeground(new Color(188, 143, 143));
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setForeground(new Color(245, 222, 179));
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setTitle("Argon Network Model");
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().setBackground(UIManager.getColor("ToolBar.light"));
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.setBackground(new Color(224, 255, 255));
        btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.setBounds(223, 329, 196, 29);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Route CNA");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(22, 11, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblTyp = new JLabel("typ");
        lblTyp.setBounds(22, 36, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblTyp);

        JLabel lblSkcna = new JLabel("sk_cna");
        lblSkcna.setBounds(22, 67, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblSkcna);

        JLabel lblSktyp = new JLabel("sk_typ");
        lblSktyp.setBounds(22, 92, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblSktyp);

        JLabel lblSkver = new JLabel("sk_ver");
        lblSkver.setBounds(22, 117, 71, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblSkver);

        JLabel lblPrefilterfilename = new JLabel("prefilterfilename");
        lblPrefilterfilename.setBounds(22, 142, 105, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblPrefilterfilename);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(122, 8, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(122, 33, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(122, 64, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setBounds(122, 89, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_3);
        textField_3.setColumns(10);

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setBounds(122, 114, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_4);
        textField_4.setColumns(10);

        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setBounds(122, 139, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_5);
        textField_5.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("prefiltertype");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(22, 167, 88, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setBounds(122, 164, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_6);
        textField_6.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("postfilterfilename");
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(22, 192, 88, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);

        textField_7 = new JTextField();
        textField_7.setBounds(122, 189, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_7);
        textField_7.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("postfiltertype");
        lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(22, 217, 86, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_3);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("xfm");
        lblNewLabel_4.setBounds(22, 240, 46, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_4);

        textField_8 = new JTextField();
        textField_8.setBounds(122, 214, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_8);
        textField_8.setColumns(10);

        textField_9 = new JTextField();
        textField_9.setBounds(122, 237, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_9);
        textField_9.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_5 = new JLabel("gelcatnumbersource");
        lblNewLabel_5.setBounds(22, 265, 116, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_5);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_6 = new JLabel("gelcatnumbersink");
        lblNewLabel_6.setBounds(22, 290, 88, 14);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_6);

        textField_10 = new JTextField();
        textField_10.setBounds(122, 262, 377, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_10);
        textField_10.setColumns(10);

        textField_11 = new JTextField();
        textField_11.setBounds(120, 290, 379, 20);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textField_11);
        textField_11.setColumns(10);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBounds(22, 369, 652, 186);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.getContentPane().add(textPane);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setBounds(100, 100, 711, 613);
        frmArgonNetworkModel.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Folks Please advise I have added the pojo as advise but how would I link the hit of button generatenetworkmodel so that finally xml is generated please advise

Answer (score 1):

Create a Java bean according to the structure of `<route...>` and annotate it using javax.xml.bind.annotation, call it `Route`. After the input is submitted, create a `new Route` and call the setters using data from the swing form. Create a JAXBContext, instantiate a Marshaller from it and marshal to a String, which may then be displayed.

The overall effort will be small, using e.g. your IDE's feature for autogenerating getters and setters.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "route")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Route {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "cna")
    protected String cna;
    public String getCna(){ return cna; }
    public void setCna( String value ){ cna = value; }
    //...
}
```

This is how to marshal:

```
void marshal() throws Exception {
    Route route = new Route();
    route.setCna( "cnavalue" );
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( Route.class );
    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty( "jaxb.fragment", true );
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    m.marshal( route, sw );
    System.out.println( sw.toString() );
}
```

You must define an action listener for the button:

```
btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.setActionCommand("generate");
btnGenerateagonnetworkmodel.addActionListener(this);
```

And in the same class add:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("generate".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        // create the Route object
        // marshal to string
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but still not I am able to grasp could you please explain in detail, if possible can you please show me the sample bean of it and how to annotate it please explain in detail

Comment: Also found a snippet showing how to marshal. The property setting omits the processing instruction `<?xml...>` and I added the forgotten @XmlProcessorType

Comment: I have generated the pojo as shown below but I have the query that how would I link the hit of button and then xml would be generated.

Comment: Added setup of a listener - plenty of examples to be found elsewhere.